# C# Kusto.Data ingore ssl certificate errors

Tags: c#, azure, ssl, azure-data-explorer

I'm connecting to ADX using the Microsoft.Azure.Kusto.Data package. The certificate doesn't validate:

`The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure: RemoteCertificateNameMismatch`

Is there any way to ignore ssl errors while testing? Since I don't(?) have access to the HttpClientHandler I'm unable to set the handlers ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback.

```
var provider = KustoClientFactory.CreateCslQueryProvider("connectionstring");

var reader = await provider.ExecuteQueryAsync("database", "query");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to call `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback` property bypass SSL certificate validation. You can add this line before you create the query provider and execute kusto query.

```
// Set the ServerCertificateValidationCallback to always return true
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

Also add the `using System.Net;` to your namespaces. More Info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.servercertificatevalidationcallback?view=net-8.0).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried that, but without success unfortunately